# Taking the value of a variable for unitSystem in maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a variable: units. This contains either metric or imperial.

Ok, so in Google maps directions the following is happening:

```
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
    unitSystem: UnitSystem.METRIC
};
```

My noobish question is: How do i change "unitSystem: UnitSystem.METRIC" into "unitSystem: units". I simply don't know what Google is expecting for as a value. Cant find it in docs either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As statued in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix?hl=fr

> unitSystem (optional) — The unit system to use when displaying
>   distance. Accepted values are:
>
> google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC (default)
>
> google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL

So I guess you could do :

```
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING,
    unitSystem: unit == 'metric' ? google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC : google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
};
```

Comment: That did the trick. I also see i forgot a bit. It needed to be google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL (or METRIC)

Comment: @Matt you're right, I'll update my answer for those who wonder the same thing.